# TFS + Eclipse (+Maven) Pends my built files (target, bin, gen folders) even though they are ignored

Tags: eclipse, maven, tfs

I've been looking around the Internet for an answer but don't seem to be able to find one. I have a very strange problem that now occurs every time we rebuild our projects. We get pending changes for all our files that change--even if they are ignored in .tpignore. This is of course specially annoying and frustrating with target, bin and gen folders that change on every rebuild.

We had the following structure:

```
Main (TFS branch)
+- Project1
|  +- pom.xml
|  +- .tpignore
+- Project2
|  +- pom.xml
|  +- .tpignore
etc...
```

After doing some Maven structural changes, adding parent projects and especially an aggregation project, we ended up with the following structure:

We had the following structure:

```
Main (TFS branch)
+- aggregationproject
|  +- Project1
|  |  +- pom.xml
|  |  +- .tpignore
|  +- Project2
|  |  +- pom.xml
|  |  +- .tpignore
+- pom.xml
etc...
```

That is, the difference is that all projects were moved down one extra folder in the file structure.

I'm not sure if it is the change with the folder but it happened after the change (and frankly it's strange if it is since .tpignore-paths are relative from the folder they are in). We had no problems with this before.

Also, its strange because Eclipse really tells us that the folders are ignored besides the folder name: [ignored].

I've tried to Right click>Team>Unignore, check in the new .tpignore and try to ignore it again but it doesn't work.

Updated by teammember:

.tpignore looks like this:

```
\Q/tests/bin/\E.*
\Q/tests/gen/\E.*
\Q/obj/\E.*
\Q/target/\E.*
\Q/.settings/\E.*
\Q/gen/\E.*
\Q/bin/\E.*
```

Really in need of help!
Thanks a lot,
Johannes

Comment: Have you tried also using Eclipse's Ignored Resources (Window > Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources)? Add a pattern like `**/target/**` and see what happens.

Comment: That might work for me but it's not really a good way to go. All other developers in the team would have to do the same and any other developer starting in a year would have to add it. We want it in the CMS.

Comment: Not sure what the `\Q` and `\E` are for (I don't have a TFS-enabled Eclipse in front of me right now).  Referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413275(v=vs.100).aspx#tpignorefileformat it seems like you want to add something like `/target/.*`

Comment: Did this used to work before you changed your project structure to include a top-level aggregate project?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the paths being pended?

Comment: @davidfmatheson: `\Q` and `\E` specify quoting in PCRE.  Everything between `\Q` and `\E` is automatically escaped.

Comment: Maybe .tpignore must be at the top level?  One file with `/Project[0-9]*/target/.*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. Your comment on the fact that it appeared only once your moved your project under an aggregation project triggered the answer for me.
It seems the tfs plugging is only taking into account the .tpignore from the master project even if eclipse is showing otherwise.
So I just set the .tpignore to include all subfolders with target, .claspath, .settings and .project

Comment: You are right. We actually fixed the problem with the solution you provided. However, just a couple of weeks after we switched to Git actually so I forgot this SO question. 
Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Thank you for this! My solution was to use an eclipse resource filter instead for this aggregate project as TFS plugin ignores filtered resources. I think it would be helpful if you provided your .tpignore